# Почему при коннекте сигнала-слота обязатеьно нужно писать &Class::Slot?

Tags: c++, qt

Вообще, конечно, с амперсандом очевиднее, что берётся указатель на функцию. Но! Ведь это вовсе не обязательно. На сколько я помню в Си:

```
     function == &function
(*ptr2func)() == ptr2func()
```

Так почему тогда при коннекте сигнала со слотом (без &) выводит ошибку?

> error: reference to non-static member function must be called

Comment: функции и методы отличаются. Вот... А если статический метод, то амперсанд не нужен

Comment: функцию_член нужно искать  только  в "коробке" класса..  Без   
амперсанда  будет искаться  не функция_член, Без     квалифицированного имени поиск будет  по всем файлам.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Правила C++ разрешают преобразование](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.func) (в т.ч. неявное) функции в указатель на функцию, однако, подобное преобразование не статических функций-членов в указатели на функции-члены не разрешено.

Поэтому для получения адреса не статической функции-члена необходимо явно "запрашивать" адрес с помощью унарного оператора `&`.

Также стоит учитывать, что оператор `&` [требует](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#3.1) квалифицированного имени не статической функции-члена. Пример:

```
struct some
{
    void foo();
    void bar()
    {
        &foo;//ошибка - foo не квалифицированный идентификатор (unqualified-id)
        &some::foo;//ок - some::foo - квалифицированный идентификатор (qualified-id)
    }
};
```

Comment: *"преобразование ... не разрешено"* Больше того, даже просто `foo` или `some::foo` написать нельзя - нужно или вызвать, или амперсанд поставить.